# Posix signals and qt library

Tags: qt, signals

Is there in Qt a signals class wrapping up the posix signals library (the one to catch SIGSEV, SIGABT etc.)? I'm writing a qt application and I would prefer to avoid to mix up the two signals system if it's not necessary. Thanks.

Comment: I think that Qt and posix signals are not comparable: qt signals are for communications (request/response) and posix signal to handle kernel signal, which normally interrupt processing.

Comment: the mouse click event is also a signal sended by the operating system, I suppose. Qt wraps it and you can write your "handler" to manage it. Maybe you are right, i'm only speculating.

Answer (score 3):

Qt's signals and posix signals are entirely different things. The only "mixup" between them is in a human head, because they happen to be named with the same word. There is no reasonable way to "mix up" the two, unless you're just confused yourself.

It doesn't make all that much sense for Qt to wrap the posix signals, because they are not cross-platform. The closest thing to posix signals on Windows would be the AIO callbacks, because those are truly asynchronous as well IIRC.